# Program started with child_process.spawn stops working after some time, but child_process.exec works

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

The following command encodes an input video and outputs out.mkv.

```
var default_settings = { "width":1920, "height":1080 };
var settings = Object.assign({}, default_settings);

var encoding_args = ["--of=mpegts", "--ovc=libx264", `--ovcopts=profile=main,preset=veryfast,level=4,crf=20,maxrate=5000k`, `--vf=lavfi=[format=yuv420p,yadif=mode=1:deint=1,scale=(iw*sar)*min(${settings.width}/(iw*sar)\\,${settings.height}/ih):ih*min(${settings.width}/(iw*sar)\\,${settings.height}/ih),pad=${settings.width}:${settings.height}:(${settings.width}-iw*min(${settings.width}/iw\\,${settings.height}/ih))/2:(${settings.height}-ih*min(${settings.width}/iw\\,${settings.height}/ih))/2]`, `--oac=aac`, `--oacopts=ac=2,b=160k`];
var mpv_args = ["input-video.mkv", "-v", '--no-config', '--log-file=mpv.log', ...encoding_args, "--o=out.mkv"];

console.log("mpv "+mpv_args.join(" "));
var mpv = child_process.spawn("mpv", mpv_args);
```

In the command prompt, the same command it works perfectly.
If I join the arguments into a string and use child_process.exec, it works perfectly.
If I use child_process.spawn, it works for about 5 seconds... and then the encoding pauses. No crash, no exit, just pauses.

Tried using Node 10, 12 + 13 (Windows 10 64 bit). Issue is present in all.
Is this some kind of buffer limit issue? How do I get around it while still using spawn?

Comment: For playing with large files I would consider using other more functional packages such as [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa)..give it a try :)

Comment: I've tried using execa and reducing the amount of messaging put out via stderr and 
It's helped, it used to pause at around 7 minutes, now it can run for just over an hour before pausing... however this process in order to be useful needs to run practically indefinitely.
There's definitely some kind of buffer limitation I'm coming up against.
That said, the child process's maxBuffer is set to 100MB and it's not reaching anything like those levels.
If someone could provide some possible fixes I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `mpv` buffer is getting filled up. Try reading from the buffer although you does not do anything with it.

```
 const mpv = spawn('mpv',[/*arg1,arg2,.. */])

   mpv.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      // read from buffer
    });

    mpv.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      // console.error(`this.mpvProcess stderr: ${data}`);
    });
    mpv.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Failed to start child process.', err);
    });
```